# Remain only used font subsets while splitting PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I am using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to split a PDF document into separate pages as PDF files. Each file seems to be too large as **all** fonts used in the input PDF are saved into **all** result pages, which is apparently not very clean.

Code of splitting is as below. Notice `PdfSmartCopy` and `setFullCompression` doesn't help to reduce size (which I have no idea why).

```
public List<byte[]> split(byte[] input) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(input);
    List<byte[]> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    int pageCount = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
    int pageIndex = 0;
    while (++pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        Document document = new Document(pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfCopy pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
        pdfCopy.setFullCompression();
        PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfCopy.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageIndex);
        document.open();
        pdfCopy.addPage(pdfImportedPage);
        document.close();
        pdfCopy.close();
        pdfFiles.add(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    }
    return pdfFiles;
}
```

So is there a way in Java (iText or not) to solve these problem?

### Update with demo PDF

Here is [a 377KB PDF using multiple CJK fonts](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqgozcbs7k4m40z/cjk-with-fonts.pdf?dl=0) where any page in it using 1 or 2 fonts. The summary size of sub-PDFs is 1.2MB. Considering CJK fonts are very bloated, I would like to find a way to remove unused font and even remove unused characters in used fonts.

So my idea is to remain only used characters in used fonts and embed them in sub files and then un-embed all other fonts. Any advice?

Comment: If each page uses all the fonts you'll get all the fonts in a single page (this is a bit of circular logic, isn´t it?). I'm not sure what you would expect.

Comment: Actually each page use only several characters. Each sub-PDF should apply only used fonts contains used characters (i.e. the font subset I wrote in the question title).

Comment: You'll have to show us the pdf, I suspect you are being too optimistic.

Comment: As long as the OP does not share the PDF in question, we can only guess. One possibility is that all the pages share a single resource dictionary (or at least a single font resource subdictionary). This would imply to iText that each page *may* use all those fonts; thus, iText would add all fonts to each split PDF. In such a case you could write a pre-processor which (using iText low level APIs) would give each page, xobject, pattern, and Type 3 font character its individual resource dictionary with only used resources after scanning the respective content stream(s) for used resources.

Comment: I've share a demo PDF file in the question. Hope @mkl 's solution fits.

Comment: Unfortunately the approach from my previous comment won't work as described as the problem is not the assumed one: The resource dictionaries are not shared, there simply are merely a handful of fonts in the file and each page uses 3 or 4 of them. In the split PDFs, therefore, most fonts are copied to multiple files which makes the sum of the sizes of the split files so much larger than the size of the original file.

Comment: *So my idea is to remain only used characters in used fonts and embed them* - You would have to implement a preprocessor which would walk the pages, xobjects, etc., determine for each of them the actually used glyphs from each font, create subset fonts and replace the currently associated fonts by those subset fonts. This is not easy, most probably beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer, but should be possible using the building bricks iText offers.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, that helps a lot.